Integrate Zebra RFID40 SDK with flutter Application
Download SDK from Zebra Dev and try to integrate it into my flutter application using plugin type.
It Gives API3 Not found error coming continuesly.
zebra_rfid_sdk_plugin this plug in is working but it was old.
I need latest version.
Help To move forward

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
